# I can't find seq2seq module in tensoflow repository

Tags: tensorflow, bots, lstm

I am reading tensorflow tutorial on seq2seq models. It has mentioned the location of the source code in t***ensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/seq2seq.py***. But after I go there (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/python/ops) I couldn't find the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `seq2seq.py` was moved to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/python/ops/seq2seq.py on commit  [d438a07a2f50401c6a1d5a644512cd46fba4da4f](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/d438a07a2f50401c6a1d5a644512cd46fba4da4f) on Dec 14, 2016.